# Bash timeout loop: commands timeout without starting

Tags: python, bash

I have a very simple bash script for running another script in a loop. Here's a simpler version of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))
do
    echo "$i"
    timeout --foreground -s SIGKILL 30 python parent.py args || echo "Timeout"
done
```

Args are, of course, i-dependent options I don't include for simplicity.
After some runs, I see the following output:

```
42
Timeout
43
Timeout
etc
```

The problem is that parent.py prints some results very quickly, after ~ 3 seconds, and then goes on with some more stuff that requires ~ 20 seconds, with the exception of rares cases which I want to take care of via timeout.

Is there anything else needed to make the timeout work? I couldn't find anything, so I tried to look in different directions. I used the htop command and notice that I am working on 100%(400% actually). I found something that may be the cause of the problem, but first let me give you some more info on parent.py:

```
# do stuff
python child.py
```

And now on child.py:

```
# do stuff
grandchild1 = SubprocessThread(args)
grandchild2 = SubprocessThread(args)
grandchild1.start()
grandchild2.start()
grandchild1.join()
grandchild2.join()
```

And while the parent and the child weren't on htop, as expected, both grandchildren were there, eating my cpu power. I should add that according to htop they weren't zombies though, they were either running or sleeping.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? (Ideally without modifying any code in the grandchildren since they are some hundred lines long already and can be used separately.)

Comment: if the `.py`file you're launching causes code to run in the background, this could be a problem. Good luck.

Comment: Does python program spawn a child process? Children of the python program will not be timed out when `--foreground` option is specified in the `timeout` command.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Could you please specify to which python program you are refering?  Also, I only put --foreground to be able to stop them myself sometimes so if that's the source of the problem I can easily remove it.